# Does $\sum _{k=2} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}+(-1)^k}$ converge conditionally?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Discuss the convergence of the sum:

$$\sum _{k=2} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}+(-1)^k}.$$

**My answer so far:** It does not converge absolutely since

$$\left | \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}+(-1)^k} \right | \geq \frac {1} {\sqrt{k} + 1},$$

the sum of whose terms diverges. Intuitively, I think it should converge conditionally because $ \sum \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}$ does, and the $(-1)^k$ in the denominator should not make a big difference. However, I am having trouble demonstrating its conditional convergence.

Evidently, the problem is that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+(-1)^k}$ is not monotone. Let's call this sequence $a_n$. If we can show that

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty |a_k - a_{k-1}| < \infty,$$

then we're done by Dirichlet's test. But this seems to be $O(1/k)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered multiplying by the conjugate ?

Comment: This got me to $$\sum \frac {1 - (-1)^k \sqrt{k}} {1-k},$$ which doesn't seem to help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**
\begin{align*}
\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n} &= \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}} = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\left( 1-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right) \\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{1}{n} + \left[ \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{3/2}} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)  \right]
\end{align*}
The (series of the) first term converges conditionally, the second diverges, the third converges absolutely. What can you say about the sum of the three?

Comment: I believe it should diverge! Beautiful answer, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Incidentally, the above is a general method to deal with series which *almost* satisfy the assumption of the alternating series test — that is, perform a Taylor series expansion up to the point you get the term of an absolutely convergent series, and break down the expression to deal with each term separately. If they all are terms of convergent series (possibly for a different reason each), you're done (the overall series converges); if all but one of them are the terms of convergent series, but one is the term of a divergent one, then you're also done (overall divergent).

Comment: That is extremely helpful.

Comment: Hey, I notice you're at Columbia! I'm a Master's (hopefully soon Ph.D.) student at NYU. I saw you had a Leonard Cohen quote on your website; very cool.

Answer (score 7):

$$\sum _{k=2} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}+(-1)^k}$$

multiply by the conjugate

$$\sum _{k=2} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(\sqrt{k}-(-1)^k)}{(\sqrt{k}+(-1)^k)(\sqrt{k}-(-1)^k)}$$

$$\sum _{k=2} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\sqrt{k}-1}{k-1}$$

$$\sum _{k=2} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\sqrt{k}}{k-1}- \sum _{k=2} ^\infty\frac{1}{k-1}$$

The first sum converges by the alternating series test  but the second is a divergent harmonic sum .

Comment: Of course! Thanks, this one is simple too.

Answer (score 6):

Let $k$ be even, and add the $k$-th term and the $(k+1)$-th. We get 
$$\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}-2}{(\sqrt{k}+1)(\sqrt{k+1}-1)}.$$
It is not hard to show that $\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$ approaches $0$ as $k\to\infty$. So after a while the top is negative and has absolute value $\gt 1$.

The denominator is after a while less than $2k$.

So after a while the sums of two consecutive terms is negative and has absolute value $\gt \frac{1}{2k}$. It follows that our series diverges.

Comment: Nice method, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. The reason I made the calculation is that I did not know the answer off-hand, but knew that any decent estimate of the sum of two consecutives would settle the matter.

Comment: Funny, I actually mention that it is $O(1/k)$ in my question. That should teach me to have more faith in my own reasoning! (Of course, I'd have to show that it did not alternate.)