# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}-(-1)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Using rearrangements I can see that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n}$ converges, but I couldn't find any required rearrangements for above series. How both series differ? This series diverges?

Comment: What I meant is : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575967/proving-whether-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1nn-1n-converges

Comment: Just multiply and divide the term by the conjugate $\sqrt{n} +(-1)^n$ and you decompose partial sums into the sum of one that diverges $\sum \frac{1}{n-1}$ and one that converges  by the AST.  Also this is essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/455315/148510